# Is it possible to bind different values when selecting a radio button?

Tags: angularjs, object, data-binding, attributes, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons. I'd like to bind different attributes for each radio button. Eg:

```
<label>
  Foo
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="foo"/>
</label>
<label>
  Bar
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="bar"/>
</label>
```

- radio foo has values "id" : "id1", "value" : "foo"
- radio bar has values: "id" : "id2", "value" : "bar"

And the binding to a `<p>` should be something like:

```
<p>The id for selected radio is {{ radio.id }}, and value for it is {{ radio.value }}</p>
```

Resulting in "The id for selected radio is id1, and value for it is foo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can create an object for each radio button and assign id and value properties to the objects.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x9nfke0d/

Angular:

```
function Controller() {
   var vm = this;

   vm.selected_radio = null;
   vm.foo = {
      id: 1,
      value: 'Foo'
   };
   vm.bar = {
      id: 2,
      value: 'Bar'
   };
   vm.setRadio = setRadio;

   function setRadio(obj) {
      vm.selected_radio = obj;
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label>
    Foo
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-click="ctrl.setRadio(ctrl.foo)">
</label>
<label>
    Bar
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-click="ctrl.setRadio(ctrl.bar)">
</label>
```

You could go a step further and create an array of radio objects, then repeat them in a ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks, Sir. This work as expected. ng-if would be useless to me since I do need to show the selection does not matter if selected or not so I just removed it from my code.

Life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravenous52/g2h2xsq3/%20here)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = {bar:"foo"};
}]);
```

```html
<section ng-controller="MyCtrl">
{{foo.bar}}
<label>Foo<input ng-model="foo.bar" type="radio" name="test" value="foo"/></label>
<label>Bar<input ng-model="foo.bar" type="radio" name="test" value="bar"/></label>
</section>
```